# Multiprocess with WSGI

Tags: python, wsgi, multiprocess

I am developing an application with apache and wsgi. The structure of my app is like this:

*Client --> Web Server --> Dispatcher(receive http request from server) --> Worker(process the request) --> Sink(response to web server) --> Web Server --> Client*

Basically, there are 3 processes(dispatcher, worker and sink)

I am stuck on forwarding *http request/response* between these 3 processes. Is there any way to do this in Python(like *RequestDispatcher* in Java Servlet)?

Answer (score 1):

For straight proxying, see:

http://pythonpaste.org/modules/proxy.html

For higher level abstractions look at a messaging systems such as RabbitMQ. You might also be interested in task execution systems such as Celery.